# Overlay directory option while compiling kernel for Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, ubuntu-10.04

I am learning Linux kernel programming. I want to know what is --overlay-dir option while compiling linux kernel as mentioned on this pagehttp://crashcourse.ca/introduction-linux-kernel-programming/intermission-building-new-ubuntu-1004-kernel-free-lesson. Why cant I build kernel image by just the basic kernel. That page asks for downloading ubuntu maverick tree. What does the overlay directory contain? Is it required?

Also is there any other way to download that maverick kernel tree other than the git way? means if I could download some zip file otherwise the git takes a lot of time for downloading around 700 MB

Answer (score 1):

The `--overlay-dir` flag is for the make-kpkg program, which is the Debian (and Ubuntu) way to make installable packages (.deb) from kernel sources. This lets you install and uninstall the kernels you build more easily. The `--overlay-dir` tells make-kpkg where to find the files that control how the package is made. This is sometimes referred to as the `debian` directory. See http://man.he.net/man1/make-kpkg for a manual page.

I don't know about downloading less. The "magic words" are download a snapshot, but as far as I know they have to be created at the server end so, if they don't exist, you're stuck with pulling the lot.